# Split a string with "(" and ")" and keep the delimiters (Python)

Tags: python, regex

Let's suppose I have this string:

```
s = "123(45)678"
```

How can I can get this list?

```
l = ['123','(','45',')','678']
```

Comment: @hek2mgl Not really, the question is also about **keeping** the delimiters

Comment: The other question is about a regular expession split. This one is about string.split and much more straight forward

Comment: This question asks for the same solution, a capturing group wrapping the whole expression in a re.split. The duplicate mark should stay.

Answer (score 9):

If you were only interested in `'('` or `')'` then [`str.partition`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) would have been sufficient.

Since you have multiple delimiters AND you want to keep them, you can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.split) with a capture group:

```
import re

s = "123(45)678"

print(re.split(r'([()])', s))
# ['123', '(', '45', ')', '678']
```

Comment: Well but try `s.partition('(')` with `s = "123(45(678"`. You don't get `('123', '(', '45', '(', '678')` but `('123', '(', '45(678')`.

Comment: @StefanPochmann fair enough, although it's not the bread and butter of the answer :)

Comment: @DeepSpace Yeah, I know. I was surprised you even included it at all :-). And I find it a little potentially misleading.

Comment: @StefanPochmann Sorry, I didn't notice you were talking about `s.partition` in your comment.

Comment: Wonderful, thank you! How could I change this regex to consider `'['` and `']'` rather than `'('` and `')'`?

Comment: `r'([[]])'`   ...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `re.findall`:

```
import re
s = "123(45)678"
final_data = re.findall('\d+|\(|\)', s)
print(final_data)
```

Output:

```
['123', '(', '45', ')', '678']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `re`, then you could try this:

```
s = "123(45)678"
finalist = []
tempstring = ''
for e in s:
    if e!='(' and e!=')':
        tempstring+=e
    else:
        finalist.append(tempstring)
        finalist.append(e)
        tempstring=''
finalist.append(tempstring)
print(finalist)
```

Comment: Why would he want to use a solution that is 9 times longer and presumably slower?

Comment: @DeepSpace Because of regexphobia.

Comment: @Stefan Pochmann Now it should work

Comment: Yes, looks correct now. Well, for a moment I thought it's wrong to *always* do that final `append`, because for example for `"123(45)"` your result contains an empty string at the end. But then I realized that's what split does as well. So I guess @Ajax1234's answer *might* be wrong, since it doesn't do that.