# How to split a string with multiple delimiters without deleting delimiters in Python?

Tags: python

I currently have a list of filenames in a txt file and I am trying to sort them. The first this I am trying to do is split them into a list since they are all in a single line. There are 3 types of file types in the list. I am able to split the list but I would like to keep the delimiters in the end result and I have not been able to find a way to do this. The way that I am splitting the files is as follows:

```
import re

def breakLines():
    unsorted_list = []
    file_obj = open("index.txt", "rt")
    file_str = file_obj.read()

    unsorted_list.append(re.split('.txt|.mpd|.mp4', file_str))

    print(unsorted_list)

breakLines()
```

I found DeepSpace's answer to be very helpful here [Split a string with "(" and ")" and keep the delimiters (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001777/split-a-string-with-and-and-keep-the-delimiters-python), but that only seems to work with single characters.

EDIT:

Sample input:

> file_name1234.mp4file_name1235.mp4file_name1236.mp4file_name1237.mp4

Expected output:

> file_name1234.mp4
>
> file_name1235.mp4
>
> file_name1236.mp4
>
> file_name1237.mp4

Comment: do you need something like `re.split('(.txt|.mpd|.mp4)', file_str)` ? what is your input & expected output?

Comment: Is there no other delimiter? Are you sure the file names aren't null-delimited?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre That actually worked, but it puts the extensions into their own variable inside the array. Is there any way to keep the extension with the file? Input looks a little like "file_name0384.mp4file_name3489.mp4file_name9400.mp4file_name2333.mp4" etc. I would like to have file_name0384.mp4", "file_name3489.mp4", "file_name9400.mp4", "file_name2333.mp4" etc.

Comment: please [edit] your question with sample input & output, otherwise the duplicate applies.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre edited.

Comment: @user3483203 OP edited the question so it's not a dupe anymore. I'm reopening this, but I don't like to do that behind the closers back hence the heads up.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre agreed, no longer a dupe

Comment: (well given the number of questions on regex/python here, maybe a dupe of some other question, but not so obvious to search for)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In `re.split`, the key is to parenthesise the split pattern so it's kept in the result of `re.split`. Your attempt is:

```
>>> s = "file_name1234.mp4file_name1235.mp4file_name1236.mp4file_name1237.mp4"
>>> re.split('.txt|.mpd|.mp4', s)
['file_name1234', 'file_name1235', 'file_name1236', 'file_name1237', '']
```

okay that doesn't work (and the dots would need escaping to be really compliant with what an extension is), so let's try:

```
>>> re.split('(\.txt|\.mpd|\.mp4)', s)
['file_name1234',
'.mp4',
 'file_name1235',
 '.mp4',
 'file_name1236',
 '.mp4',
 'file_name1237',
 '.mp4',
 '']
```

works but this is splitting the extensions from the filenames and leaving a blank in the end, not what you want (unless you want an ugly post-processing). Plus this is a duplicate question: [In Python, how do I split a string and keep the separators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2136556/in-python-how-do-i-split-a-string-and-keep-the-separators)

But you don't want `re.split` you want `re.findall`:

```
>>> s = "file_name1234.mp4file_name1235.mp4file_name1236.mp4file_name1237.mp4"
>>> re.findall('(\w*?(?:\.txt|\.mpd|\.mp4))',s)
['file_name1234.mp4',
 'file_name1235.mp4',
 'file_name1236.mp4',
 'file_name1237.mp4']
```

the expression matches word characters (basically digits, letters & underscores), followed by the extension. To be able to create a OR, I created a non-capturing group inside the main group.

If you have more exotic file names, you can't use `\w` anymore but it still reasonably works (you may need some `str.strip` post-processing to remove leading/trailing blanks which are likely not part of the filenames):

```
>>> s = " file name1234.mp4file-name1235.mp4 file_name1236.mp4file_name1237.mp4"
>>> re.findall('(.*?(?:\.txt|\.mpd|\.mp4))',s)
[' file name1234.mp4',
 'file-name1235.mp4',
 ' file_name1236.mp4',
 'file_name1237.mp4']
```

So sometimes you think `re.split` when you need `re.findall`, and the reverse is also true.

Comment: This is great! Thank you so much! Just one question, if in the future I were to have spaces or other symbols in the file names, would this be an issue or would it work the same?

Comment: that'll work if you accept all the characters: `'(.*?(?:\.txt|\.mpd|\.mp4))'`. You may want to apply a `strip()` if needed